# Not display the correct age

Tags: sql

I have this query to display the age. However its not display age greater than 55.
The DOB is set as date in the table.

Below is the query I used.

```
SELECT
STAFF.First_Name,
STAFF.Middle_Name,
STAFF.Last_Name,
STAFF.Telephone,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) AS AGE
FROM STAFF
WHERE DOB >= 55
ORDER BY DOB DESC;
```

its displaying ages from young as 21 and so forth.

Any correction made will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the table in your question?

Comment: Is DOB the Year of Birth? Because that comparison DOB >= 55 is probably going to return everyone since it is a timestamp which would mean most timestamps would be greater than 55.

Comment: "DOB is the year of birth which is using the DATE type" not sure how to parse this, does DOB have an empty month and year?  A date object should be complete.  What comparison do you expect to happen when you compare a date to the number 55?

Comment: @user2277471, DOB >1959-12-17 is a proper date comparison, i.e. date vs date.  DOB >= 55 is date vs integer, not sure about the parsing/comparison rules on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can think up is actually using the following where clause:

```
WHERE DOB <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 55 YEAR)
```

That would compare the DOB with the current year minus 55 years.

Answer (score 1):

Probably should be

```
where AGE >= 55
```

instead of

```
where DOB >= 55
```

since comparing a date to 55 doesn't make much sense.

edit:

Since it seems mysql doesn't recognize named generated columns in the query (AGE) maybe it should be

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) >= 55
```

if you are looking specifically for people who are 55 or older.

Comment: @user2277471 Correct, it *should* be `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) `.

Comment: mysql doesn't recognize named columns?  I'm not real conversant with mysql, but this is pretty generic SQL in this query.

Answer (score 1):

I think your where clause should be this instead:

```
WHERE AGE >= 55
```